# Oracle Pivot Column in group query

Tags: oracle, pivot, oracle-apex

I have the following working query:

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
             select PSGROUP,
    PSCOLUMN as PSCOLUMN
FROM LOG_PS_STATUS
            )
    SELECT *
    FROM   pivot_data
    PIVOT (
           MAX(NULL)        --<-- pivot_clause
          FOR PSCOLUMN--<-- pivot_for_clause        
        IN  (&PS_COLUMNS.)   --<-- pivot_in_clause         

);
```

It shows results as expected:

Values:

```
PSGroup PSColumn
A           1
A           2
A           3
B           1
B           2
B           3
C           3
```

Result is giving like:

> PSGroup(Column vertically)  PSColoumn(Horizontally)

```
           1 2 3
A
B
C
```

Now I want to make PSGroup column as group of PSColumn and output should be like:

```
A
 1 2 3
B 
 1 2 3
C
 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listagg:

```
WITH pivot_data(PSGroup,PSColumn) AS (
    select 'A',           1 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'A',           2 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'A',           3 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'B',           1 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'B',           2 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'B',           3 FROM dual UNION all
    select 'C',           3 FROM DUAL),

    res(PSGroup,PSColumns) as(
     SELECT PSGroup, LISTAGG(PSColumn, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (order by PSColumn)
        FROM   pivot_data
        GROUP BY PSGroup)

    select DECODE(PSColumns,NULL,PSGroup,NULL) AS PSGroup, PSColumns from(
    select PSGroup, NULL as PSColumns from res
      union all
    select PSGroup, PSColumns from res)t
      ORDER BY t.PSGroup, t.PSColumns NULLS first
```

Also note that `LISTAGG(PSColumn, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (order by PSColumn)` is limited to 4000 characters

Comment: Please explain your query

Comment: @Muhammad Muazzam in subquery 'res' I 'group by PSGroup' then in every group concatenete PSColumn value in it delimiting by space order by PSColumn ascending. Now I have 3 records like this  'A
 1 2 3' Then in last query I divide every row into 2: first have only column PSGroup, second - concateneted PSColumn.